# How to use CASE WHEN to group data?

Tags: postgresql, group-by, case-when

I am trying to created an updated bucket column to better group my data.

I have matched the 'name' column to the 'term' column to group the data into buckets. However, the name is matching to different terms. I want to create an updated bucket that blankets all the mismatched terms. Something like:
IF bucket CONTAINS 'dining' THEN 'dining' END (partitioned by the name)

I'm not sure how to best go about this. I think CASE WHEN when be best but open to suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Too cryptic, to be of much use for the general public. Please make your case clear. And  post data as text, never as image.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the aggregate function with window function.

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN bucket = 'dining' THEN 'dining' ELSE 'healthcare' END) OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY name),
       *
FROM T
```

Comment: Thank you D-Shih! This is the solution I went with and it worked :)